# Give an Array a Value

Tags: c#, wpf, arrays

I am trying to make a game where an image appears, and if it is not clicked the image should disappear. I need help giving my array a value of three, then subtract it in another method.

Code:

```
NameCount = -1;
NameCount++;

        Grid.SetColumn(mole, ranCol);
        Grid.SetRow(mole, ranRow);
        grid_Main.Children.Add(mole);

        for (int i = 0; i < NumofImages; i++)
        {
                //Where I must give a value to the array of the array to 3 for every image that appears.
        }

 //Where I am trying to make the image disappear after 3 seconds.
        private void deleteMole()
        {

            NumofImages = TUtils.GetIniInt(Moleini, "NumPictures", "pictures", 8);
            NumberofImages = Convert.ToInt32(NumofImages);

            for (int j = 0; j < NumofImages; j++)
            {

                CounterArray[j]--;

                if (CounterArray[j] == 0)
                {
//Not Sure How to delete image
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: What array are you trying to populate? Do you want every element of the array to be 3, or only certain elements? This question isn't very clear.

Comment: Why are you using an array do act as a 3 seconds counter instead of using Timers?

Comment: I am trying to give CounterArray[] a value of three, so in the second method I can subtract by one every second, then delete the image. Sorry if the question is not descriptive.

Comment: Why would you use an array for that? Couldn't you just use an int?

Comment: @SeanCogan I am using an array because I need to keep track of all the images being created.

Comment: Then couldn't you just use a foreach loop to loop through each element of the array and set them to 3?

Comment: @SeanCogan Can you give an example? I am new to C#, and it would be very appreciated. :)

Comment: Sure thing, I'll post it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could keep track of the images in another array.

After you add the image to the view you should also add it to the array:

```
images[j] = mole;
```

Then later:

```
if (CounterArray[j] == 0)
{
    grid_Main.Children.Remove(images[j]);
}
```

But using static arrays and separating data is not a good idea.

If you can you should better aggregate all the metadata and the image together in the same structure:

```
class Mole
{
    public int Counter { get; set; }
    public Control Image { get; set; }
}
```

and manage them in a single *List<Mole>*; adding and removing them will be simpler.

Here is some code that illustrates the idea (won't compile):

```
class Mole
{
    public int X { get; set; }
    public int Y { get; set; }
    public int Counter { get; set; }
    public Control Image { get; set; }
    public bool IsNew { get; set; }
}

class Test
{   
    IList<Mole> moles = new List<Mole>();

    private static void AddSomeMoles()
    {
        moles.Add(new Mole{ X = rand.Next(100), Y = rand.Next(100), Counter = 3, Image = new PictureBox(), IsNew = true });
    }

    private static void DisplayMoles()
    {
        foreach (Mole mole in moles)
        {
            if (mole.IsNew)
            {
                grid_Main.Children.Add(mole.Image);
                mole.IsNew = false;
            }
        }
    }

    private static void CleanupMoles()
    {
        foreach (Mole mole in moles)
        {
            mole.Counter -= 1;

            if (mole.Counter <= 0)
            {
                grid_Main.Children.Remove(mole.Image);
                moles.Remove(mole);
            }
        }
    }

    static void Main()
    {   
        while (true)
        {
            AddSomeMoles();

            DisplayMoles();

            Thread.Sleep(1000);

            CleanupMoles();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you give more information on the second option, it seems more useful.

Comment: In your class you store a field in a dynamic array of type "List&lt;Mole>" and you add and remove elements from it as you make new images appear or old disappear.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I still confused about it, can you gave me an example on how I would add and remove the image?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to give every element in a List a certain value, use a foreach loop. In this case, it would look like:

```
foreach(int currentElement in CounterArray)
{
    currentElement = 3;
}
```

This will loop through each element of the List and set it to 3.

EDIT: If you're using an array, which you are, you would do the following:

```
for (int i = 0; i < CounterArray.Length; i++)
{
    CounterArray[i] = 3;
}
```

Comment: No this wont work because "currentElement" is a copy of an element in the array so the array will stay the same.

Comment: Thanks! But I am getting an error for the "currentElement" within the loop. The error says that it can not assign to currentElement because it is a 'foreach iteration variable'. Help?

Comment: @Andrew I updated my answer to work with an array, but I'd recommend using a List for this kind of thing, like Serious suggests in his answer.